# Kali Linux can't see my windows partitions!

Tags: linux, partition, kali-linux

I'm trying to install Kali Linux alongside with my Windows 8.1 using live USB , but I can't because Kali is unable to see my partitions and unallocated space in my disk which I prepared 50GB unallocated space to install Kali in there.

Kali just let me to install on all disk and doesn't show any partition or unallocated space so I can install there! Help please.

OS: Windows 8.1 (64)
Disk style: MBR
My partitions(5): C,D,E,F,G
Disk size: 250 GB

I even created `ext4` partition with `Minitool Partiotion Wizard` but still Kali wasn't able to see it! When i run `fdisk -l` command on kali terminal I can see partitions but even GParted can't detect partitions.
I created bootable USB disk for Kali using Universal-USB-Installer app and everything is working fine in Live mode.
Update: These are screenshots I took:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[My disk info (XML file)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ht9k6wvc0j1hn1s/hddinfo_default.xml)

Comment: Is it have some option to configure your disks manual?

Comment: @ValeriRangelo:Yes it has. But still it can't detect any partition or unallocated space! Also `GParted` shows my disk as a 250 gb unallocated space!!!

Comment: xmm, did you try with other distro?

Comment: No!And unfortunately this is my first experience with Linux :D  But i installed Kali on VMWare before but there wasn't any problem like this one.

Comment: Don't give up. I don't known from what is your problem that's why I told you to test with other disro or Live USB. If you don't have problem then, it means the problem is in Kali.

Comment: Can you add output from `fdisk -l` or another partitioner? Even a screen shot from the Windows Disk Manager (`diskmgmt.msc`) could be helpful.

Comment: @peterph: I took screenshots and updated the question hope it helps find problem.sorry for links!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the disk has a hybrid partition table (both MBR and GPT) with both parts not in sync.

You could have a look at the second sector of the disk and (after a backup) overwrite it with zeros:

```
dd if=/dev/sda skip=512 bs=1 count=16 | command od -t c -t x1
```

backup with

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/whatever/sector1.dd skip=1 count=1
```

overwrite with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda seek=1 count=1
```

Comment: Before i go further can you look at my disk info i created from `Disk Editor` software.(XML file) http://www.mediafire.com/download/ht9k6wvc0j1hn1s/hddinfo_default.xml

Comment: It doesn't look like a hybrid PT scheme - there is a logical partition, and hybrid scheme doesn't allow that (iirc).

Comment: @peterph: So what should i do??

Comment: @peterph I have read that, too. Doesn't make sense to me, though. However: In this case the GPT would be wrong anyway so that wouldn't be an argument.

Comment: @HBS try another distribution as ValeriRangelov suggested. It really seems like a bug in Kali.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu distribution without any problem!finally i installed Kali in VirtualBox (same iso file) and it works fine!!!Thank you all :)

Answer (score -2):

Possibly Windows was shut down incorrectly. Try booting back into Windows and shutting down cleanly with Start, Power, Shutdown

Comment: OP's problem was solved 18 months ago.

Comment: How could that even screw up the partition table?