# Dual booting Kali live image on Windows 10 machine - Can't see system's partitions

Tags: partition, kali-linux

I am trying to dual boot Kali on a Windows 10 machine. I am following this dual booting installation guide (https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows/). I have gotten to the part where I am using GPart to adjust the size of the main Windows partition but I only see the "/dev/sda1" which I believe is the USB I am loading Kali from. In the tutorial, I believe all the machine's partitions should be visible. How can I see all the machine's partitions? Because I need to be able to see them if I am to resize the machine.

Machine: Dell XPS 15 7590

Machine OS: Windows 10

Dual-boot OS: Kali-linux-2023.2-live-amd64.iso

[image]

I have looked here ([Kali Linux can't see my windows partitions!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184070/kali-linux-cant-see-my-windows-partitions)) but this seems more geared towards a Linux machine (use of the "dd" command).

Also this is a view of the system's partitions from the Windows side

[image]

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361

Comment: see that dropdown box top right? any other drives there?

Comment: Hey @JaromandaX thanks for your comment. No, unfortunately

Comment: is the main drive an NVMe?

Comment: @IporSircer the problem exists regardless of distribution

Answer (score 0):

A growing number of machines now run with the onboard Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology) controller enabled with RAID, rather then having the single disk directly connected. Typically a Linux-based system can't see through the RAID controller to the disk, and this is what you also are seeing.

The solution is to disable the Intel RAID (it's pretty pointless for just one disk anyway).

However, it's not that simple as you need to warn Windows you're doing it beforehand and confirm you've done it afterwards.

Personally I have never needed to try this (I use VirtualBox, Proxmox, and ESXi) so I cannot vouch that this solution is correct.

References

- [Dell XPS 15 (7590)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dell_XPS_15_(7590))
- [Switch Windows 10 from RAID/IDE to AHCI operation](https://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/)

The gist is that you need to execute these next commands from Windows. But **before you do this, go and read the articles IN FULL**. There are some important warnings as well as comments from other users who have attempted this.

1. Click the Start Button and enter `cmd`. Right-click the result and select *Run as administrator*
2. Enter `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`. If that fails try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
3. Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup
4. Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID
5. Save changes and exit Setup, and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode
6. Open a privileged `cmd` window once again
7. Enter `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot` or `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
8. Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled

You can now resize the primary NTFS partition, disable Fastboot, and shutdown Windows.

Finally you can now restart your Linux installation. I should point out, though, that if you're relatively new to Linux then perhaps Kali [isn't the distribution to use](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/100397). There are much more friendly alternatives available such as Mint, Ubuntu, or maybe Fedora